# Large whitespaces using align environment

Tags: math-mode, align

I am trying to use the align mode to typeset a series of inequalities as shown in the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    0.9 &\leq a_t, d_t &\leq 1.1 \label{zoom}\\
    -0.1 &\leq b_t, c_t &\leq 0.1 \label{rotation}\\
    -0.05 &\leq b_t + c_t &\leq 0.05 \label{limit_skew}\\
    -0.1 &\leq a_t - d_t &\leq 0.1 \label{non_uniform_scale}.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The result I get looks like

[image]

There is too much white-space in between the variables and the second `\leq` symbol. Variations like the one below also failed to work for me,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    0.9 &\leq a_t, d_t \leq &1.1 \label{zoom}\\
    -0.1 &\leq b_t, c_t \leq &0.1 \label{rotation}\\
    -0.05 &\leq b_t + c_t \leq &0.05 \label{limit_skew}\\
    -0.1 &\leq a_t - d_t \leq &0.1 \label{non_uniform_scale}.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You've a syntax error anyway: two alignment points require `3&`. Hence an implicit ampersand is added at the end of each line, and the equations are right-aligned, as you can see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newsavebox\tempbox
\newcommand\fitbox[2][a_t-d_t]{
  \savebox{\tempbox}{$#1$}
  \makebox[\wd\tempbox][c]{$#2$}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  0.9 &\leq \fitbox{a_t, d_t} \leq 1.1 \\
  -0.1 &\leq \fitbox{b_t, c_t} \leq 0.1 \\
  -0.05 &\leq \fitbox{b_t + c_t} \leq 0.05 \\
  -0.1 &\leq \fitbox{a_t - d_t} \leq 0.1
\end{align}
\begin{align}
  0.9 &\leq \fitbox{a_t\hfill,\hfill d_t} \leq 1.1 \\
  -0.1 &\leq \fitbox{b_t\hfill,\hfill c_t} \leq 0.1 \\
  -0.05 &\leq \fitbox{b_t + c_t} \leq 0.05 \\
  -0.1 &\leq \fitbox{a_t - d_t} \leq 0.1
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

### ADD

If you want more control...
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newsavebox\tempbox
\makeatletter
\newcommand\threepart[4][\fit@sep]{
  #2 \mspace{#1 mu} &\le \mspace{#1 mu} \fitbox{#3} \mspace{#1 mu} \le \mspace{#1 mu} #4
}
\newcommand\fitbox[1]{
  \makebox[\wd\tempbox][c]{$#1$}
}
\newcommand\myfitset[1]{
  \savebox{\tempbox}{$#1$}
}
\newcommand\myfitsep[1]{\def\fit@sep{#1}}
\makeatother
\myfitsep{0}
\myfitset{a_t - d_t}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \threepart{0.9}{a_t\hfill,\hfill d_t}{1.1} \\
  \threepart{-0.1}{b_t\hfill,\hfill c_t}{0.1} \\
  \threepart{-0.05}{b_t + c_t}{0.05} \\
  \threepart{-0.1}{a_t - d_t}{0.1}
\end{align}
\centering
Increase the space around.
\myfitsep{6} % increase space
\begin{align}
  \threepart{0.9}{a_t\hfill,\hfill d_t}{1.1} \\
  \threepart{-0.1}{b_t\hfill,\hfill c_t}{0.1} \\
  \threepart{-0.05}{b_t + c_t}{0.05} \\
  \threepart{-0.1}{a_t - d_t}{0.1}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that employs an `alignat` environment instead of an `align` environment. (To determine the argument of `alignat`, one counts the maximum number of `&`s in any row (here: 3), add 1, and divides by 2. Since (3+1)/2=2, the argument of `alignat` is set to `2` in the following example.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'alignat' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
     0.9 &\leq \ a_t,d_t &&\leq 1.1 \label{zoom} \\
    -0.1 &\leq \ b_t,c_t &&\leq 0.1 \label{rotation} \\
    -0.05&\leq b_t + c_t &&\leq 0.05\label{limit_skew}\\
    -0.1 &\leq a_t - d_t &&\leq 0.1 \label{non_uniform_scale}   
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```